# How long might a tick be on a body before biting?

Tags: arthropod

I understand that a tick must be attached for roughly 24+ hours before presenting a danger of transmitting Lyme Disease. However, I am wondering how long a tick might be on my body before actually attaching itself to me.

Comment: Anecdotal: I have found ticks that have not fed on me hours after I've left the forest and changed clothes (and avoided areas I might have exposed to wayward ticks). This has certainly been the exception out of the 1000s of ticks I've had on me, but in my experience is not improbable. CDC is often a good source for tick info, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wander the body for 30 minutes to an hour before inserting their feeding parts into the skin. [Source](https://www.health.harvard.edu/a_to_z/tick-bites-a-to-z).

It entirely depends what material you are wearing, i.e. fluffy wool is difficult for them to climb on. They can fall off somewhere in the home and bite another day.
2mm nymphs climb on human skin at about 10cm per minute, so it could find the back of the knee in about 5 minutes and search for a bite site. tick [attachment site](https://www.wemjournal.org/article/S1080-6032(08)70142-X/pdf) distribution is: 9% head-neck, 5% arm,
24% stomach-groin, 7% back, 18% chest-shoulder, 25% leg-foot, and 12% hip.